# install npm module in my project

Tags: windows, node.js, command-line, npm

I have node.js project on drive "F". 
for example `F:\development\WebStormProjects\test-app\`

so, how i can install nmp module (`npm install twitter-bootstrap-node`) in that project folder?

my os is windows.

Thank's in advance.

Comment: What does `npm -version` give you?

Comment: Is there any kind of error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either add the module as dependency to your `package.json` or install it manually. In any case, typing above command in the command line *while being in your project directory* should have the desired effect.

If you've added a module as dependency then a simple `npm install` from the project root should suffice.

EDIT: Global installation of modules is not the default, if you were worried about this. You have to actively trigger it with `npm install -g $MODULE_NAME`

Comment: So your actual problem was that you were not able to go to your project folder on the command line? Just typing `F:` would also work :)